# (C++) Undefined Reference to Class File Error

Tags: c++, function, class

When I attempt to test out the methods created in my header and implementation files I get the following compile errors:

```
 undefined reference to 'main_tucker_points::points::points(double, double, double)
```

The same compile error happens with the member functions I'm trying to call.

Here is the code for my points.h file:

```
 namespace main_tucker_points
 {
     class points
     {
     public:
         //CONSTRUCTORS
         points();
         points(double x, double y, double z);

         //MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
         void set_x_point_location(double p_loc);
         void set_y_point_location(double p_loc);
         void set_z_point_location(double p_loc);

         double get_x_coord();
         double get_y_coord();
         double get_z_coord();


         double shift_x_point(double angle, char axis);
         double shift_y_point(double angle, char axis);
         double shift_z_point(double angle, char axis);

     private:
         double x_coord;
         double y_coord;
         double z_coord;
         double x_shift_coord;
         double y_shift_coord;
         double z_shift_coord;
         double x_coord_new;
         double y_coord_new;
         double z_coord_new;
         double angle;
         char axis;
     };
 }
 #endif
```

Here's the code to my class implementation file, points.cpp.

```
 #include <cassert>
 #include "points.h"
 using namespace std;

 namespace main_tucker_points
 {
     points::points()
     {

     }

     points::points(double x, double y, double z)
     {
         x_coord = x;
         y_coord = y;
         z_coord = z;       
     }  

     double points::get_x_coord()
     {
         return x_coord;
     }

     double points::get_y_coord()
     {
         return y_coord;
     }

     double points::get_z_coord()
     {
          return z_coord;
     }  
 }
```

And finally, here's the code for my main.cpp file to test out the member functions.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdio>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include "points.h"

 using namespace std;
 using namespace main_tucker_points;

 int main()
 {
     points p1(3.5, 3.6, 3.7);

     printf("Coordinates are %f, %f, %f", p1.get_x_coord(), p1.get_y_coord(), p1.get_z_coord());

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Please post your build command(s).

Answer (score 0):

Compile it in this way

```
g++ -o myfile points.cpp main.cpp
./myfile
```

make sure you have the `#include "points.h"` in both the `.cpp` files.

Comment: Thanks @RSahu, have changed it now. you may now release the down vote